# Why tension in the string is inversely proportional to cross sectional area of the string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

While doing some questions related to tension I found one which is like this:

[image]
The problem is that I have always dealt with questions having massless pully/strings or having some mass, but here I have a given creoss sectinal area of string (metal wire). Since mass of wire is not given so I can assume it to be massless.

MY work: If I forget about the cross-sectional area and then calculate the answer,it comes out to be 4mg/3 and the actual answer of question is (B) which is 4mg/3A (they have considered the effect of cross sectinal area).

So, after analysing the given conditions, I think that tension in the string is inversaly proportinal to the cross sectinal area.

Is it a correct result. If yes then why?? I shall be thankful if You can give me a derived relation of tension and cross sectinal area.

I also apologize if this question is too elementary for the site.

Comment: -1. Failure to read the question, which asks for *stress* not tension.

Comment: Its okay @sammy gerbil, it was needed so that I avoid these kind of mistakes in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to realise that the question asked for the stress not the tension (force).
$\rm stress = \dfrac{\rm force}{\rm area}$

So you did the right thing.
You first worked out the tension (force) and then to find the stress you need to divide by the cross sectional area.